# Does anyone have a sample Android module for titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am new to Titanium and Android development. We are planning to use titanium for Android (and iPhone) app development. Before we close on the 'Titanium' could any one send a sample code for android module for titanium.

What we are expecting is if we got stuck with some issues in titanium or a custom built functionality we will be developing the module in java(or objective-c). (not much idea of that development too .. as i am basically from .net). Then we need to use the functionality in Titanium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh my god, this question and answer are too out dated.

first of all, read ALL the official document(http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile) you have to read all of them, including android&ios part.

At the same time, you MUST download the official's sample module project, you have to learn them by reading the complete code: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.moddevguide

if you want to have a quick idea, checkout this series of articles of titanium module: http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2013/10/android-module-development-part1.html  ( maybe the titanium version here is a bit out dated, but the knowledge is basically the same. )

I am writing articles about Titanium module. basically , it's a hard work, because you have to be familiar with both Android and IOS, you have to:

1. learn the android/ios hello world tutorial
2. be clear about the concept in android and ios.
3. be familiar with java/object-c
4. be familiar with Titanium's module related components(such as TiApplication, TiConvertor ... )
5. be familiar with the module related commands ( such as: java ANT, gradle, build.py... )

I am write the Chinese book of titanium, and there are already some articles about writing module for Android ( in Chinese: 
http://siwei.me/blog/posts/lession-9-sdk
)  I will let you know (and translate to English ) once the book is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the guide to develop custom Android modules for Titanium:

[Titanium Android Module Developer Guide](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/support/module/android/documentation/android_module_dev_guide.md)

And here's a fairly complex sample module (for barcode scanning):

[titanium-barcode](https://github.com/mwaylabs/titanium-barcode)

**UPDATE**

The newer Titanium versions (> 1.8) changed the modules, an updated guide could be found here (thanks to Giorgio for pointing it out):

[Android Module Porting Guide (Titanium 1.8.0.1)](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Module+Porting+Guide+for+1.8.0.1)

Comment: I am getting this as build error  [INFO] logfile = 
[TRACE] app property, ti.android.google.map.api.key.production : GET_ME_FROM_GOOGLE
[INFO] Building mywaysbarcode for Android ... one moment
[INFO] plugin=C:\ProgramData\Titanium\plugins\ti.log\0.1\plugin.py
[ERROR] Build Failed (Missing plugin for ti.log)

Comment: try to clean up your build folder and force a full-rebuild, anyway I'm not the creator of the module, if it has some problem (but I don't think it should have any), open an issue on GitHub

Comment: and go get your key from google, instead you don't want to still have errors

Comment: @ShadowCloud Things have changed with Titanum Mobile 1.8.0.1, see https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Module+Porting+Guide+for+1.8.0.1, the example you refer to is related to Titanium mobile 1.6.0